# What is mono16 and how does it encode a pixel?

Tags: c++, openni, ros, asus-xtion

In my lab, we're using ROS and an Xtion Pro, and we need to characterize the IR "noise" from another piece of equipment that we're using. We wrote a ROS node to do so, using the `openni_launch` and `sensor_msgs` libraries. As soon as we run it, we get the printout "Pixel encoding: mono16".

We don't recognize the format and Google was of little aid. In order for this node to be useful, we need a mental or programmatic way to parse that into a format we recognize.

Comment: It's almost certainly 16-bit greyscale, but may have to determine big-endian vs little-endian.

Answer (score 0):

Mono16 is 16bit monochrome encoding. This document might be helpful for further understanding of pixel formats: http://www.visiononline.org/userassets/aiauploads/file/Pixel_Format_Naming_Convention_1-1-00.pdf